# I can't combine both Percentage and Total in a Cognos Crosstab

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I can't combine both Percentage and Total in a Cognos Crosstab

My goal is to create a crosstab that would show both percentage and total. The problem that I'm getting is that I can only choose one between PERCENTAGE and TOTAL. If I tag the Aggregate Total equal to Percentage then it will affect the TOTAL column to appear as percentage as well. If I tag the Aggregate Total equal to TOTAL then is will display 100% on both PERCENTAGE and TOTAL columns.

TOTAL COLUMN aggregate Total is = Total and Rollup Aggregate Function is = Automatic

PERCENTAGE COLUMN aggregate Total is = Calculated and Rollup Aggregate Function is = Automatic

EXPECTATION

[image]

REALITY

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the expressions for each data item in the query? You have the percentage aggregate as 'calculated' which is generally used when you supply your own aggregate calculation.

Comment: but when I tag a Percentage column in a crosstab as calculated, it also affect the TOTAL column which is tagged as total

Comment: What you suggest shouldn't happen if the calculations are independent. That's why I asked for you to provide the expressions for all related data items.